# Spring Integration Zip - .gz files

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying spring-integration-zip - useful stuff - and was wondering if it (somehow) can also uzip .gz files apart from zip ones?
Moreover, I wanted to change `workDirectory` ("java.io.tmpdir") for unzip transformer - is there a way to change UnZipTransformer class in xml config, I do not see such possibility or maybe I'm missing something (I know I can use Java Config) - as it is in case of `int:splitter` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. We don't expose `work-directory` into the XML configuration.

Please, raise a [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/issues) on the matter.

Meanwhile you can use:

```
<int:transformer>
    <bean id="unZipTransformer" class="org.springframework.integration.zip.transformer.UnZipTransformer">
        <property name="workDirectory" value="D:\tmp"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>
```

And no we don't support `GZIP` format for (un)compression.

The project has been built on top of [zt-zip](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip) library. So, this Spring Integration Zip extension really provides functionality only for ZIP archives.

Feel free to fill out an issue on the matter as well.